# Databricks - Create Table Options for ignoring first row

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to create a table but the file I am loading just has system info in the first row with no delimiters and the columns don't correspond with the rest of the file.  Is there an option to exclude the first row - I've tried header being true or false.  File is in Text Format but I have also tried CSV as the option

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS *tablename*
USING TEXT
OPTIONS (
delimiter '|'
,header 'true'
)
LOCATION *locationname*

Comment: I have managed to load this by replacing header 'true' and changing the type to CSV:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename USING CSV OPTIONS ( delimiter '|' ,skiprows '1' ) LOCATION locationname

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I have written to get the required output:

- Specify the Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) file path details in the code below.
- Read the ADLS file path and a **samplefile.txt**.
- Use the `spark.read.text` API to read the specified text file directly into a PySpark DataFrame named **text_df**.
- Create a Delta table from the DataFrame.
- If you want to skip the first row (header), you can use the header option and set it to false when reading the text file.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
file_path = "abfss://folder02@dileepstggen2.dfs.core.windows.net/"
text_file_location = "samplefile.txt"
text_df = spark.read.option("header", "false").text(f"{file_path}{text_file_location}")
text_df.show(truncate=False)
delta_table_name = "delta_text_table"
text_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").option("header", "false").option("delimiter", "|").saveAsTable(delta_table_name)
text_df.show()
```

```
+-----------------------------------+
|value                              |
+-----------------------------------+
|System Info|Column1|Column2|Column3|
|1|A|10|X                           |
|2|B|20|Y                           |
|3|C|30|Z                           |
+-----------------------------------+
```

[image: Delta table in Azure Data Lake Storage]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this by adding skiprows '1' to my script

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename USING TEXT OPTIONS ( delimiter '|' ,skiprows '1' ) LOCATION locationname